# Update multiple columns in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to update multiple columns in Entity Framework. I now use this :

```
var user = new Relations { Id=1, Status = 1, Date = DateTime.Now, Notification = 0 };

db.Relations.Attach(user);

db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Status).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Notification).IsModified = true;
db.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Date).IsModified = true;

db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a better way to update columns without repeating the code `db.Entry(user).Property` several times ?

Comment: Is there any reason don't you simply set entry state as modified?

Comment: you need to mark `entitystate` modified for `user` object only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can Use `EntityState` Like this:

```
var user=db.users.Find(userId);
user.name="new name";
user.age=txtAge.text;
user.address=txtAddress.text;
context.Entry(user).State=Entitystate.Modified;
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use:

```
var existingUser = context.Set<User>().Where(u => u.Id == 1);
context.Entry(existingUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(user);
```

Or you can use a 3rd lib like [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff).

Comment: Why is it not accepted yet? less verbose and works well. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yo update an entity you don't need to do this:

```
// build your entity object with new values
var user = new Relations { Id=1, Status = 1, Date = DateTime.Now, Notification = 0 };
//attach as modified in one single step
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
//execute update
db.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes you are setting all entity fields and there isn't RowVersion field in your entity. Extra steps would be required to manage these other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
using (var db = new YourDb())
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

When an item is fetched via the context it is

**automatically tracked in that context unless you change the default behavior**.

So you could simple do:

```
var txtInputAge = 18;
var txtAdrressLine1 = "Some cool place"

//fetch the user
var user = db.Users.Find(userId);

//change the properties
user.Name = "new cooler name";
user.Age = txtInputAge;
user.Address = txtAdrressLine1;

//call save changes
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Update** - Add would look like

```
//create new entry
User user = new User();

user.Name = "new cooler name";
user.Age = txtInputAge;
user.Address = txtAdrressLine1;

//add to context
db.Users.Add(user);

//call save changes
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

using (var dbcontext = new MyModel())
{

```
var matchedRecords = dbcontext.DummyTable.Where(e => e.code.Equals(entry.code) &&
e.isValid.Equals(true)).ToList();
matchedRecords.ForEach(e => e.isValid = false);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

}