# Update multiple columns in MVC Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have table with more than 25 Fields in it. It has some column with huge data (`nvarchar(MAX)`). It has **User** table like :

```
ID  // Primary key 
Name
Mail
Contact
RegFees
.
.
. //  about 25 Fields
Narration   // Nvarchar(Max)  may have upto 10000 chars
Tag        // Nvarchar(Max)  may have upto 15000 chars
```

Now i have to update only *Name,Mail,Contact* fields in it.

I have gone through several so posts like [update 1 field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642371/how-to-update-only-one-field-using-entity-framework), [update multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617864/update-multiple-columns-in-entity-framework).
But these require data to be loaded for that specific user ID and then Update it like :

```
 var u = dc.Users.Where(a =>a.ID.Equals(i.ID)).FirstOrDefault();
 if (u != null)
   {   
    // Note : ALL the data of 25+ columns is loaded including nvarchar(Max)
    // it will decrease performance as Whole Data is loaded first.

    u.Name = i.Name;
    u.Mail = i.Mail;
    u.Contact = i.Contact;
    }
```

is there any better way that does not require to load entire data ?

Comment: Actually both links show how you can do that w/o loading data from the database - first link in the accepted answer, second link in the question itself.

Comment: @IvanStoev i am unable to understand that, could you pls provide a code for my scenario ( for user table ) ...

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below approach for updating few fields in a table.

```
dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Update [User] Set Name = @Name, Mail = @Mail, Contact = @Contact Where ID = @ID", new SqlParameter("@Name", "YourName"), new SqlParameter("@Mail", "newMail"), new SqlParameter("@Contact", "newContact"), new SqlParameter("@ID", 1));
```

Comment: its not pure, like : using  .Property or SetModifiedProperty ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a EFish approach (no SQL statement) you can treat your `UPDATE` as a batch statement using [Entity Framework Extensions](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Batch-Update-and-Delete), now re-branded [Entity Framework plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended).

I have used the old version, but the one seems to work similarly. For your particular case:

```
dc.Users.Where(u => 
    u.ID = userID)
    .Update(x => new User() 
          { 
              Name = name, 
              Mail = mail, 
              Contact = contact
          });
```

AFAIK, this will directly issue an `UPDATE` against the database (it is not included in the transaction by default). However, a custom transaction (i.e. TransactionScope`) can be used when needed.

Comment: i am using mvc4,,, its showing error'Update' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of  users)'

Comment: @Admin - did you include a reference to Entity Framework Plus? These batch statements (`UPDATE`, `DELETE`) are not included within EntityFramework.

Comment: I can not add dll or reference other than Microsoft Own DLLS...  is there any microsoft update for Entity Framework Plus ?

Comment: @Admin - I am not aware of such Microsoft assemblies. However, you can easily use the direct query approach (`Nitesh`' answer)

Answer (score 0):

Add a stored procedure to the database for updating the few fields in the table.  You can use the entity framework to call a stored procedure which updates the fields in the database

One of these articles should help

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/299/entity-framework-code-first-and-stored-procedures

Comment: Stored Procedure not a solution, since i can use SQLCE 4.0  in my mvc application and that DOES NOT SUPPORT  stored Procedures...